# Redirect to different pages on user registration and user login in drupal

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-rules

I am trying to set up two rules in Drupal 6 to do the following - 
rule 1:
   ON event User account has been created
   Redirect to page A

rule 2:
   On event User has logged in
   Redirect to page B

However, no matter what I do it never redirects to page A. Its always triggers rule 2 and goes to page B. I tried weights etc. Also couldn't find anything useful in the scarce documentation. 
Please help!

Comment: Please add more information (screenshots?) about your rules. It should be no problem to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the module [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination). It should be capable of doing what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about actions in Drupal is all about weight... but when it comes to redirection it's all about **last call**. If you're redirecting twice (once for registration and then for login) the final redirect will be the last one. So if your user registers (receives a redirection) but then automatically logs in, the redirection will be the last one after log in event.

I you're already using rules... I think LoginDestination module will be an overkill.